# Getting object not found when compiling models in dbt cloud vs Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am trying to use DBT Cloud to create derived views in Snowflake.

The underlying tables in Snowflake are themselves views that have been shared with me via the.

However, when I try to preview a super basic model:

`SELECT * FROM xxxx;`

I keep getting into the error:

```
Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
Object 'xxxx' does not exist or not authorized.
```

I've tweeked privileges and other things, but I can't figure the right configuration to get this working.

Any ideas?

Comment: The easiest way to troubleshoot is to check QUERY_HISTORY on Snowflake side: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html checking the actual query, the role, database and schema

Comment: You should also check your quoting policy in dbt -- on Snowflake dbt doesn't quote table/view names by default, so if the views don't have SHOUTING_CASE names, you might get this error. You can check the compiled sql that dbt is running in the `target/compiled/` directory inside your dbt project